# How to exclude one object's reflection from another object? (Cycles)

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, reflection

How do I stop the green man from casting a reflection onto the motorcycle?

[image]

Comment: if you go in the Properties panel > Object > Visibility, you can switch off the Glossy option, but it will also switch off his reflection for every object of the scene